# Is X-Frame-Option configured on server side in tomcat 5.5.33 possible? If so how?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I need to add  X-Frame-Options to prevent Clickjacking in my application. But am unable to find any source for adding that in tomcat of the version 5.5.33 . Is there a solution or workaround possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of tomcat is dated 2011, version 5.5 has been archived in 2012 - this might be a good time to think about upgrading.

As a short term fix (in case you don't get any answer to how your problem can be solved with just this ancient version) this is a good usecase for having Apache httpd serve ports 80 and 443, then forward to tomcat with `mod_jk`, `mod_proxy` or `mod_proxy_jk`. In Apache you can just conditionally or unconditionally set the appropriate header using the `Header` directive.